# how to put a button at the bottom of the listbox in wp7?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, xaml

Windows phone 7.5 and above.

I wanna add a button at the bottom of the list, so the user can click it to fetch more articles.

I put a button inside a listbox in xaml. But it does not work, when the itemsource of the listbox get binded at the runtime, the button disappear.

how to approach the goal?

Comment: Do you need selection? If not, put an ItemsControl and your button inside of a StackPanel inside of a ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to implement that as part of your binding to set the last item to display 'load more...'.

For example, if your listbox template shows a picture, a header and then some description text and you retrieve 25 items each time. What you can do is grab those 25 items from your source then manually add an item with header 'load more...' then bind that list. You can then easily check if the 'load more...' item was clicked by checking the header text or if your model has some unique identifiers for each item then you can give the 'load more...' item an id of -1 or some other unique value.

The other solution is to automatically detect when the users scroll to the end (or near the end) of your list box then automatically load more data. Check these tutorials on how to implement this:

[Loading Data when the User Scrolls to the End of a List in Windows Phone 7](http://danielvaughan.orpius.com/post/Scroll-Based-Data-Loading-in-Windows-Phone-7.aspx)

[Detect when a ListBox scrolls to its end (WP7)](http://blog.slimcode.com/2010/09/11/detect-when-a-listbox-scrolls-to-its-end-wp7/)

[WP7 – How To Extend ListBox When Reaching Last Item](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2011/04/06/wp7-how-to-extend-listbox-when-reaching-last-item.aspx)